# How to get Spring Boot default validation reponses in @WebMvcTest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

When I run my application and there is a validation problem with the request to one of my endpoints, the response has a lot of information on what exactly went wrong. It looks similar to this:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2017-11-23T13:18:05.923+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
  "errors": [
    {
      "codes": [
        "Size.sensorParameters.openText",
        "Size.openText",
        "Size.java.lang.String",
        "Size"
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "codes": [
            "sensorParameters.openText",
            "openText"
          ],
          "arguments": null,
          "defaultMessage": "openText",
          "code": "openText"
        },
        20,
        1
      ],
      "defaultMessage": "size must be between 1 and 20",
      "objectName": "sensorParameters",
      "field": "openText",
      "rejectedValue": "xewrewrwerwer weew ewewewrwe ew wewewewerew we ewrwerwe ewr ",
      "bindingFailure": false,
      "code": "Size"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Validation failed for object='sensorParameters'. Error count: 1",
  "path": "/api/monitors/89c94880-9423-4990-892b-6bbd8e90b1e6/sensors"
}
```

If I test this in an `@WebMvcTest`, I do get the same 400 response, but the response body is empty.

Is there some extra setup I should be doing in order to get the same behaviour in my unit test? I am using the `@Autowired` MockMvc object I get from the test framework without any extra setup from my side currently.

Comment: Can you provide the code for your test?

Comment: First thought is that @WebMvcTest disables full autoconfiguration. See doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html.

Comment: Yes, probably so. But I wonder if I can add some extra annotation to have that exception handling code active for this test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rossen Stoyanchev (the inventor of `MockMvc`) pointed out in a related issue on [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12692)...

> the body is taken care of by Spring Boot which configures error mappings at the Servlet container level (see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling) and since Spring MVC Test runs with a mock Servlet request/response, there is no such error mapping.

He goes on to advise that one use `MockMvc` to test controller logic and mappings, but that one write an *in container* integration with Spring Boot to test the error mapping support in the Servlet managed by Spring Boot.

If you feel that Spring Boot should somehow (magically) provide the error mapping support in conjunction with `MockMvc`, I'd suggest you raise an issue on GitHub against the Spring Boot project.